# any reason to not use nginx (free) to load balance Exchange 2019?

Tags: nginx, exchange, load-balancing, haproxy

I've prototyped load balancing my Exchange 2019 mailbox servers (2 servers in a DAG) using nginx free edition using the streams capability. I am aware that this is only a Layer 4 solution, and hence doesn't terminate the connection or do any traffic inspection at all. I am OK with this limitation. However, some colleagues have advised against using nginx, but don't have reasons to offer other than "nginx free doesn't work with Exchange" (which is at least somewhat untrue). Am I going to run into issues down the road? Should I instead use haproxy? (Kemp LoadBalancer also looked interesting, but is pricey unless you use the free version, which is limited to 20Mb/s). My top priority is stability/reliability. Well, I guess my real top priority is price (I have little to no budget for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I've prototyped HAProxy, I can't believe how much better it is than nginx free for load balancing. Active health checks, a nice stats interface, much better default logging, and much more. With just an hour of tuning, I am observing much faster reconnection of my Outlook clients after a server failure than I was able to achieve with nginx with days of experimentation and tuning. HAProxy also offers a free path forward if I want to move to reverse proxying Exchange vs just load balancing it.

I do want to emphasize that nginx free DOES work (the numerous claims that free doesn't load balance TCP and UDP are wrong), but I believe HAProxy to be a much better solution for this application.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that only Nginx Plus has [TCP and UDP Load Balancing](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/) required for load balancing SMTP, POP3 and IMAP, whereas Nginx is only capable of [HTTP Load Balancing](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/).

It could work, if you only need HTTPS, which Exchange uses for Outlook on the web, AutoDiscover, web services, ActiveSync,
MAPI over HTTP, RPC over HTTP, OAB and EAC. From [Load balancing in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/load-balancing?view=exchserver-2019#protocols-in-exchange-server), [protocols](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/load-balancing?view=exchserver-2019#protocols-in-exchange-server):

> Beginning with Exchange 2016, all native Exchange clients use the HTTP
>   protocol to connect to a designated service, with HTTP cookies
>   provided to the user at log in which are encrypted using the Client
>   Access services SSL certificate.

Using **Nginx** (open source) as a load balancer would mean you don't support other than native Exchange clients, because you don't provide SMTP/IMAP access to your mail servers. Your colleagues might refer to this, but you should ask them.

**Nginx Plus.** For a fully supported (but not free) alternative, there's a deployment guide for [Load Balancing Microsoft Exchange Servers with NGINX Plus](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/deployment-guides/load-balance-third-party/microsoft-exchange/).

**HAProxy.** Load balancing Exchange 2019 should be pretty similar to load balancing Exchange 2016. Mikael Hansson has written a short introduction on [Load Balancing Exchange 2016 behind HAProxy](https://www.oxcrag.net/2017/09/23/load-balancing-exchange-2016-behind-haproxy/), making a few points on what may differ from [Exchange 2013 Load Balancing with HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/microsoft-exchange-2013-load-balancing-with-haproxy/).

Comment: The free nginx supports TCP load balancing, too. Using streams, it seems it should be possible to load balance any Exchange client and even SMTP. In further testing, I am seeing weirdness with Outlook clients -- they are still trying to contact a failed DAG member, presumably using cached server info or something. I will keep investigating, and may also prototype the HAProxy solution.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I ’m not familiar with these three-party tools. For more accurate help, you can go to the [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) forum for help.

In addition, from [Load balancing options in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/load-balancing?view=exchserver-2019#load-balancing-options-in-exchange-server)

> Using DNS is the simplest option for load balancing your Exchange
>   traffic . With DNS load balancing, you only have to provide your
>   clients with the IP address of every Mailbox server. After that, DNS
>   round robin distributes that traffic to your Mailbox servers. The HTTP
>   client is smart enough to connect to another server should one
>   Exchange server fail completely.

Comment: I first tried using DNS, because I do like simplicity. However, Outlook clients weren't failing over properly, and this also wasn't an adequate solution for external clients, since they are coming in through NAT and I have only a single IP address.

Answer (score -2):

The answer from Esa is excellent, HAProxy is definately a better solution for most projects than the [crippled version of NGINX](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/nginx-vs-haproxy/). [Exchange 2019](https://www.loadbalancer.org/applications/microsoft-exchange/) is easy to load balance (and well designed).

Ignore people who tell you to terminate SSL on the load balancer (that just ads hassle).
But one problem that a lot of people hit with using HAProxy is that because it is a layer 7 reverse proxy it hides the real server/client IP address.

So how do you set up relay protection on you SMTP reciever?
Your only two options as far as I'm aware are either:

- Using [LVS Layer 4 DSR](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/15-years-later-we-still-love-dsr/) which is awesome
- Or configuring [TProxy](https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/configure-haproxy-with-tproxy-kernel-for-full-transparent-proxy/) for HAProxy (which is a pain in the neck)

Comment: I do think it is important to note that the assertion in Esa's post that only Nginx Plus has UDP and TCP proxying is incorrect. btw, I'm using the DSR approach.

Comment: Oops! That should say I am NOT using the DSR approach.